# monitor mode with winpcap 4.1.3 TPLINK

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-xp

Can I do monitor mode usinng 4.1.3 winpcap, I have a TP-LINK W727N wireless adapter, and I want to know how I can achieve this ? Note: I will not be using npcap.

Answer (score 1):

That particular TP_Link does not support monitor mode (all articles I researched). It could be the card version or, it could be the RealTek chip used. RealTek is not seen highly in the world of WiFi Monitoring.

The TP Link TL-WN722N V2/V3 apparently does support monitor mode.

[TP Link Monitor Mode](https://nooblinux.com/how-to-enable-monitor-mode-on-tp-link-tl-wn722n-v2-v3/)

Some sources may be confusing, and lead you to believe that you can only enable monitor mode on TP-LINK TL-WN722N v1 because it has one of the required chipsets for monitor mode, Atheros AR9271, and that you can’t enable it on V2/V3. You can, however.

sudo ifconfig wlan0 down

sudo airmon-ng check kill

sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor

sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

sudo iwconfig

Here’s the output you should be seeing. You can see that the adapter is set to Mode: Monitor.

**Another adapter** (which does not use the RealTek chip) is the Panda line of adapters.   I use here the Panda PUA08 and it works fine.